# (Flutter) How change current location marker in google maps?

Tags: flutter

I'm already get the location, I only want change the current location marker in google maps.

[This is my current location marker, this is what comes standard on Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlzH6.png)

[Now, I want change for this, but i dont know how i can change de color and create a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugSl8.png)

Can someone explain to me in detail how I can do this?